# Qt inherit QGraphicsScene how add items to scene inside object?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene

My class inherits form QGraphicsScene (`class MyGraphicsScene : public QGraphicsScene`). I have problem with adding items inside object. For example in virtual function mousePressEvent I get segmentation fault when I'm training to add line item:

```
 void MyGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event){

     MyObject *myobject = new MyObject(mainwindow);
     QGraphicsLineItem *line = new QGraphicsLineItem();

     line->setLine(0, 0, 23, 43);
     addItem(line);
     addItem(myobject);
     QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(event);
}
```

How I should adding items to object each time when I clicked mouse button ?

`class MyObject : public QGraphicsObject`

I don't understand it because in scene container there are pointers of `QGraphicsItem` type, so when I cast to `MyObject` type it works fine, but when I add `QGraphicsLineItem` the type is different from scene list type ?

Comment: Are you 100% sure the error occurs at that line? The snippet you posted seems correct to me and I'm using very similar code in my projects.

Comment: When I was debugging it occurred exactly in that line. It seems that line is added but every time I get this kind of error. When I comment addItem(line) it starts working.

Comment: When I use the exact 4 lines in my program it works fine, adds the line to the scene and continues to work without any issue so I maybe something else happens when you add the line? Some signal emitted which triggers something else? You should probably create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the issue

Comment: Is it possible that I get this because I am adding two different object to scene: custom graphic object and graphicLine ?

Comment: By custom graphics I meant object which inherits by QGraphicsObject:
`class myObject: public QGraphicsObject`

Comment: Just by itself that should not be a problem either. But you said earlier that the error occurs when you only add the line. Now you have another object in your question. Please _reduce your code to a minimal example_ which **reproduces the error**. Otherwise it is impossible to help you. Also please be exact on which line the error ocurrs _exactly_.